# How to make the shapekey influence separate object's position?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, shape-keys

I have a model which consists of the separate body, eyes and jaw meshes. I added a shapekey, which increases the neck's lenght. When I change the shapekey's value to 1 the eyes and jaw stay in the original positions. I want them to move together with a body mesh, while changing the shapekey's value. Is it possible? Is this kind of parenting exist?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [vertex parenting](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Groups_and_Parenting#Vertex_Parent) to have the objects follow parts of your mesh. This has similarities to the [hook modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Deform/Hooks).

Select the teeth, <kbd>shift</kbd> select the head, go into edit mode, select the target vertex (only one or three vertices can be selected, three vertices allows rotation when following) press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to parent the other selected object to the selected vertex.

[image]

Be careful as I expect you will deform the face for animation and the parenting will keep working. You could add an extra unattached vertex that moves with the neck shapekey but isn't used in facial animation, or maybe you could choose three vertices located one in each ear and one at the top of the head that won't get deformed in animation. You may also need the armature to follow so that any animation will happen relative to the new location, or parent a facial armature which will take the teeth and eyes with it.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Although I doesn't work in every case ,since the model I've made is some kind of mesh editor (you can modify every part of the mesh using shapekeys). I think it is impossible to make one shapekey work fine, without the other causing undesirable result. Or maybe I haven't found a good solution yet? Anyway, great tip man.